# What are advantages on running services as dedicated user

Tags: service, redis

When I want to run some service, eg. Redis - then, according to following [Guide](http://library.linode.com/databases/redis/ubuntu-10.04-lucid) I'm advised to create dedicated user and init script when I want to run it on production.

What are main advantages of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most common reason: say there is some security flaw in a service, that allows an outside attacker to execute commands on your machine after pushing some random data to an open port (this happens from time to time, though I haven't heard about it happening in redis)

if the service runs as root, this flaw can now affect the entire machine, wiping disks, stealing databases, security keys etc etc. if the service runs as a restricted user that has only access to what is essential for this service to run (a couple of directories to hold the data, read access to  /etc/something, executing /usr/bin executables, and so forth), the amount of damage that can be done is reduced dramatically.

but it doesn't have to be a malicious attack. a while ago, some software that has to do with display drivers in linux, ran a daemon as root, and a typo in a script caused the line that should be "rm -rf /usr/lib/something" to be "rm / usr/lib/something", wiping clean whole partitions.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard about bumblebee :) And breaking into service which runs daemon as root very good example and answer to my question. Thanks Dvir!

Answer (score 2):

- Security can be for example an issue.
- It improves isolation of service from other services that can be run on the same machine